# vim-go with coc.nvim: how to rename a package?

Tags: go, coc.nvim, vim-go

I have a file `work.go` opened in `vim-go`. It's in package `oldpackagename`.

I want to refactor and rename it to `newpackagename`. Is there some tooling for that? The reason is, the initial assumptions for `oldpackagename` do not apply anymore.

I know I can do search and replace stuff, but usually either

- `GoRename` resp.
- `nmap <leader>rn <Plug>(coc-rename)`

work just fine on automatically renaming all occurrences.

But for the package name, I get:

> vim-go: [rename] SUCCESS vim-go: cannot rename the identifier at the
> requested position
> for `GoRename` and:

> [coc.nvim] Error on rename: The element can't be renamed.
> for `coc.nvim`.

Is package renaming different? Do I have to use search/replace or are my configs maybe corrupted?

Comment: `gopls` [doesn't support renaming packages yet](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/41567); `gorename` had package renaming also still in a [TODO list](https://cs.opensource.google/go/x/tools/+/refs/tags/v0.1.5:refactor/rename/rename.go;l=124).

Comment: OH....I see. Thanks @BenjaminW.. I feel this could actually be added as an answer, and I would accept it...if you care :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the hood, vim-go uses either [`gorename`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/gorename) or [`gopls`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/tools/gopls) to run `:GoRename`; the default is now `gopls`.

Both of these don't support renaming packages:

- [Open issue for `gopls` to support package renaming](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/41567)
- An [explicit mention of "package renaming" as a TODO feature](https://cs.opensource.google/go/x/tools/+/refs/tags/v0.1.5:refactor/rename/rename.go;l=124) in the `gorename` source code

For coc.nvim, I'm not sure, but it seems to integrate with `gopls`, so the same lack of support would apply.

Answer (score 1):

`gopls` should support package renaming soon (Oct. 2022).
Its integration with [vim-go](https://github.com/fatih/vim-go) should take advantage of that as soon as the feature is released.

[Issue 41567](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/41567#issuecomment-1276830292) mentions [CL 420958](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/tools/+/420958)

> ### `gopls/internal/lsp`: add support for package renaming
>
> Users can now rename packages by performing a rename on the package name in package declarations.
>
> The editor will prompt user with a dialogue text field to change the package name.
> This rename feature then do the following:
>
> - Rename all the external imports of the renaming package. In case there is renaming conflicts within a file, the feature repeatedly try fresh names constructed by appending new package name with number of try times so far until succeed.
> - Rename all the internal references to the renaming package from its files.
> - Rename the directory of the renamed package and update the imports' paths of any packages nested under the renamed directory.
> - Rename the test package with the new package name and suffix "`_test`" with the current test package name ends with "`_test`", or just the new package name otherwise.

However:

> ### Todo:
>
> - Add a test for the case when the renaming package's path contains "`internal`" as a segment.
> - Allow edit to the whole package path not just only the last segment of the package path
> - Reject renaming if the renamed subpackages don't belong to the same module with the renaming package
> - Check the `go.mod` files in the workspace to see if any replace directives need to be fixed if the renaming affects the locations of any `go.mod` files